# Remove Excel taskpane close button using VB.NET VSTO

Tags: vb.net, excel, winapi, vsto, customtaskpane

I believe the the title says it all. Does anybody know how to remove the close button of task-pane in Excel using VSTO (VB.NET)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should simply be like this:

```
taskPane.CloseButton = false;
```

(I tested this in my current Addin that uses some 3rd party software that uses TaskPane manager and it works there. This is why I am not completely sure if this will work for you, especially after reading [this topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/fa3118ed-ba37-4ee4-ba26-e81b7e2352c8/) that concludes that there is not direct way to do it).

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for the code without any 3rd party controls.

Comment: You tried my suggestion and it didn't work? If so it is possible that there isn't a way to do it like the topic I linked to you suggests.